# Make "Switch account" menu default in new Google multiple sign-in interface

Tags: gmail, google-multi-login

Google's new interface requires an additional step to switch accounts:

1. Click email/ID in upper right-hand corner
2. Click "Switch account" (This is the additional step.)
3. Click account or "Sign in to another account..."

Now, I rarely use the first menu items that show up ("View profile, Account settings, Privacy"), but I use the switch account functionality many times per day.

**Is there a way to directly display the list of accounts by default? (the menu as it appears after clicking "Switch account"**

*Extensions/User-side JavaScript OK; solutions for Chrome and Opera browsers preferred.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/97229

> This simple script currently just adds a few styles to show the available accounts on first click.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/16341)

It replaces the `Sign Out` link with a select list of accounts, so you you can instantly switch between accounts without logging out.